# Why driver.execute_script function is giving an unexpected token error for special characters and numbers in string?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have written a python script using selenium library which will send all the list of keywords to textarea. Since this send_keys method is very slow, so i have chosen to do the same action using execute script which is pasting all the keywords to textarea in fraction of seconds. However for some keywords in my list which ends with tilde & numeric value for example : '"Very fast"~2'. the double quotes enclosed and ~2 are part of my keyword that i wanted to paste along with my words, they are not part of python string format they are actually required to paste with tilde 2.

```
list_of_words = ['"Fresh apple"','"green apple"~2','"spoiled apple"~1']

# Converting list to string since value in execute script accept only string not list
list_to_string = str(list_of_words)


driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('section').getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0].value="+list_to_string )
```

why this code is giving me an error called : Javascript Unexpected token '~'

I cannot replace the ~2 character to execute since i need them in my textarea. the output shall be pasting all keywords in the list to textarea as shown below without any commas because since i converted the list to string so now my string of all keywords has commas.

expected output in textarea

```
"Fresh apple"
"green apple"~2
"spoiled apple"~1
```

Comment: Did you try this:     list_of_words = ["Fresh apple", "green apple~2", "spoiled apple~1"]. use only double quotes not single quotes, also put ~ symbol and the following numeric character inside the double quotes.

Comment: I know but as per the application requirement i need to send the keywords in the above mentioned format only otherwise application will not accept. the tilde with numeric value should be outside double quotes of the keyword.  the whole keyword is anyway inside the single quote in the list then why it is not accepting as a string?

Comment: I am using python `3.10.8` and selenium `4.7.2` webdriver-manager `3.8.5` I am not getting this error in chrome driver, do you want me to share my test code ?

Comment: Sure could you please share it i will try.  I will upgrade to the above stated versions if required.

Comment: @DickensAS Could you please share the code which you tested

Comment: @Ashcube given my code below, `str` is not a proper solution, if you have 100 elements you may not get all the elements, figure out a better solution like `iterator` , `collections`, `datastructures` ... etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the documentation or [str](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str)

> Return a string version of object. If object is not provided, returns the empty string. Otherwise, the behavior of str() depends on whether encoding or errors is given, as follows.

so using `str` is not a proper solution, but to answer your question, I am giving the code anyway

So technically you get below as a string including the brackets

```
['"Fresh apple"', '"green apple"~2', '"spoiled apple"~1']
```

Now you need to replace `[`, `]`, `,`  everything manually so that you will get

```
"Fresh apple"\n"green apple"~2\n"spoiled apple"~1
```

above output is your unit test outcome which needs to be sent to browser javascript below is the full code

**HTML**

```
<div id="section">
   <textarea cols=30 rows=10></textarea>
</div>
```

**Python**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import time 

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()))

driver.get("http://localhost:8082/test.html")

low = ['"Fresh apple"','"green apple"~2','"spoiled apple"~1']

los = str(low).replace("'","").replace(', ', '\\n')[1:-1]

driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('section').getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0].value='" + los + "'")

time.sleep(10)
```

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Define the element's locator using XPATH or CSS_SELECTOR.

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].value='" + list_to_string + "';", <locator of text area>)
```

Comment: what do you mean by <locator of text area> Iam already referring to the text area using getElementById and getElementsByTagName.

Comment: Updated the code. I don't think in Javascript, you can enter the value with the format you mentioned in your code, instead, you can try my suggestion.  Because with your code, I tried to enter the value in your format in the 'text area' available at the bottom of this page itself, it's not working, got the same error. I tried in the 'console' also, same error. Otherwise, sorry, best of luck.

Comment: Yeah correct, let me see what best i can do to retain the format if possible because send_keys method taking ages to load 500 keywords to textarea so i pivoted to try this JavaScript approach.